# How to create a center pivot point for mutiple mesh files?

Tags: mesh

I have a Butterfly which exists out of 7 different mesh files. How can i create one centered pivot point

for this file. So that when i import it into my Compositing software (fusion9) the butterfly has a centered pivot point?

[image]

Cause at the moment when i export the .abc file out of Blender --> and i import it into Fusion the pivot point is way of.

[image]

So my questions is:

How can i select all the meshes --> and create a pivot point for the whole butterfly?

Comment: Is your bug object at global origin (0, 0, 0) and unrotated when you exported it?  It appears to be in same pose as in blender file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all meshes to have the same, centred origin:

- Select all meshes you want to average the centre from
- Snap - Cursor to selected (or place your 3D cursor where you want their centre to be)
- Snap - Origin to 3D cursor

I use the "3D View: Dynamic Context Menu" addon to easily find these

You could also join the meshes together with Ctrl+J, depends on the use case I suppose.

I guess in your case for export you might want to move their centre to the origin of the scene afterwards to have their centre be the same in the export

[image: 3D Cursor to Selected]
[image: Origin to 3D Cursor]
[image: Resulting Origins]

Comment: thanx for your reply.
I don't see the option --> Snap --> Origin to 3d cursor
I do have the option Transform --> Origin to 3d cursor

I have tried this, but this also doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Select objects
RMB > Set Origin > Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)

[image]